# Sum specific rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, row

I have a table like this:

```
id | player | points
----------------------
1  | A      | 2500
2  | B      | 3800
3  | C      | 1500
```

I would like to sum (for example) just the points of the players A and C. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered `where`?

```
select sum(points)
from t
where player in ('A', 'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to sum A and C together and keep the rest separately like this:

```
select
    case when player in ('A','C') then 'A or C'
    else player end player,
    sum(points)
from t
group by
    case when player in ('A','C') then 'A or C'
    else player end;
```